# Using p2 director to create a target platform gives error: "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found."

Tags: eclipse, p2

I've been attempting to build a brand new target platform using p2 director.

I've been using this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET _INSTALLABLEUNITS_=<very long list>
SET _TARGETDIRECTORY_="C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\projects\localtpbuild\p2DirectorTestDebugLocal2"
SET _REPO_=<redacted for company security>
@ECHO Running P2...
@ECHO on
C:\IBM\IBM_DevelopmentPackage_for_Eclipse_Win_X86_32_6.5.5\eclipseDevelopmentPackage\eclipse\eclipsec.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -vm C:\IBM\IBM_DevelopmentPackage_for_Eclipse_Win_X86_32_6.5.5\eclipseDevelopmentPackage\ibm_sdk80\jre\bin\default\jvm.dll -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -roaming -repository %_REPO_% -installIU %_INSTALLABLEUNITS_% -bundlepool %_TARGETDIRECTORY_% -destination %_TARGETDIRECTORY_% -p2.os win32 -p2.ws win32 -p2.arch x86
@ECHO off
@ECHO P2 complete.
```

The command runs, but I get the following error:

```
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: EMF Model Query SDK 1.12.0.201805030653 (org.eclipse.emf.query.sdk.feature.group 1.12.0.201805030653)
 Missing requirement: EMF Model Query OCL Integration 1.12.0.201805030653 (org.eclipse.emf.query.ocl.feature.group 1.12.0.201805030653) requires 'org.eclipse.ocl [3.4.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: EMF Model Query SDK 1.12.0.201805030653 (org.eclipse.emf.query.sdk.feature.group 1.12.0.201805030653)
  To: org.eclipse.emf.query.ocl.feature.group [1.12.0.201805030653]
Application failed, log file location: C:\IBM\IBM_DevelopmentPackage_for_Eclipse_Win_X86_32_6.5.5\eclipseDevelopmentPackage\eclipse\configuration\1547763033802.log
```

The log file effectively has the same information.

I thought that an installable unit would get all of its dependencies, but it seems the dependency in question isn't even in the repository.

Any ideas how I can work around this issue?

Comment: I don't use this but I believe you must list all the repositories to be used as a comma separated list to the `-repository` argument.

Comment: The _REPO_ parameter in the batch file points to a repository, which I’ve redacted for company security. I’ve thought about finding a second repository to add to this one, but I’m surprised I would need to do that - shouldn’t the repository work on its own? If this is a flaw in the repository, can it be fixed?

Comment: Yes, `org.eclipse.ocl` of version >=3.4 and <4.0 is missing. You have to [add this required dependency into your repository](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html) or use an additional repository that contains it.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to locate a repository that contains the dependency and add it. That link to adding dependencies locally will also come in handy. Much appreciated.